# dot button not working in javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I'm making this calculator app and everything is working fine and I'm almost done, but there's an issue with the dot button on the screen when I click it, it gives me this error in the console:

```
The specified value "." is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

Here's the code:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter A Number...." step="0.01">

<td><button id="dot">.</button></td>
```

---

```
dot.addEventListener("click", function() {
    input.value += this.textContent;
    re1 = input.value;
})
```

I also added this bit of code to prevent any special characters from the input:

```
input.onkeypress = function(e) {
var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
if ("1234567890qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM.".indexOf(chr) < 0)
    return false;
};
```

but also if I comment it out nothing happens, so I don't know where the issue is.

any help would appreciated and thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/person_0/pen/wvawBaY) with the app so you can see the issue for yourself

Comment: Well `.` by itself is not a valid number

Comment: Problem is `.` and `#.` is not considered valid so it is not going to show up in input type number./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change type to `text` instead of `number`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter A Number....">
```

When you add the dot `.` to your input it is not a number anymore and thus `type="number"` is throwing an error.

The input element with `type="number"` is actually a string field which is then converted to a number when passed internally

Comment: okay, I changed it to text instead of number and it worked but there's something annoying about it, which is when I refresh the page using f5 it appears in the text input, other than that it's working just fine

Comment: What exactly is appearing in the text input?

Comment: everything is working fine but if I press f5 to refresh the page "F5" appears in the text input